# How to properly re-run a deadlocked trasaction in TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

In TSQL (SQL Server 2012), is this a proper way of re-running a transaction that was killed due to deadlocked - it was chosen as the deadlock victim.

*EX:  "Transaction (Process ID 118) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."*

```
__RETRY_BATTLE__:
BEGIN TRY 
    begin transaction BATTLE 

    ---- DO STUFF 
    ---- May call other stored procs 


    COMMIT transaction BATTLE 


END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK


    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205 -- deadlock occured in this SP 
        OR (ERROR_NUMBER() = 50000 AND left(ERROR_MESSAGE(), 8) = 'DEADLOCK' ) -- deadlock occured in some called SP 
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
        GOTO __RETRY_BATTLE__
    END                         

    RAISERROR('error ya!',11,1) 
    return

END CATCH
```

Comment: Do you know why the deadlock occurred? If not, retrying is just taking another blind shot. If your schema and/or query is designed to deadlock, you're just setting yourself up for groundhog day. Unlike dropped connections, deadlocks are almost never transient; they are symptoms of important underlying issues which could involve poor index design, bad queries, incorrect/suboptimal isolation level, etc... Figure out the root cause and fix that instead of trying to mask the issue with a blind retry. If you can share details on both queries and the schema, folks here can help with RCA